# How to initialize an object in DWScipt?

Tags: delphi, dwscript, smart-mobile-studio

What is the equivalent of this JS code in DWScript please?
I use the DWScript codegen.

```
// JavaScript:
DoIt({name:"Fred", size:{width:3,height:2}});
```

I tried anonymous record but it seems not working:

```
var obj: variant;
    obj := record
      Name = 'Fred';
      Size: variant = record
         Width = 3;
        Height = 2;
      end;
    end;
```

The generated JS code with DWScript Codegen is:

```
var obj = undefined,
      /// anonymous TRecordSymbol
      function Copy$a$460(s,d) {
         return d;
      }
      function Clone$a$460($) {
         return {

         }
      }
      function Pub$a$460($) {
         return {
            "Name":$.Name$8
            ,"Size":$.Size$5
         }
      }
      /// anonymous TRecordSymbol
      function Copy$a$461(s,d) {
         return d;
      }
      function Clone$a$461($) {
         return {

         }
      }
      function Pub$a$461($) {
         return {
            "Width":$.Width$4
            ,"Height":$.Height$2
         }
      }
      obj = {Name$8:"Fred",Size$5:3};
      alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you an example that will help you answer your own question

First, create a new type, something along the lines of:

```
type
  TDimensions = record
  published
    Width: integer;
    Height: integer;
  end;
```

Next, you need to somehow use it. Imagine you click a button, a bunch of data is gathered from a few input fields, you sanitize your input and dispatch it. As a start use something like:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonClickHandler(Sender: TObject);
var
  dimensions: TDimensions;
  payload: Variant;
  serialized: String;
begin
  dimensions.width := StrToInt(self.W3EditBox2.Text);
  dimensions.height := StrToInt(self.W3EditBox3.Text);

  payload := TVariant.CreateObject;
  payload.name := self.W3EditBox1.Text;
  payload.size := dimensions;

  asm
    @serialized = JSON.stringify(@payload);
  end;

  writeln(serialized);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. Haven't seen your response. 
I have used  anonymous classes finally: DoIt(class name:="Fred"; size := class Width :=3; Height := 2; end; end);